# Subqueries with EXISTS vs IN - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, query-optimization, subquery

Below two queries are subqueries. Both are the same and both works fine for me. But the problem is Method 1 query takes about 10 secs to execute while Method 2 query takes under 1 sec.

I was able to convert method 1 query to method 2 but I don't understand what's happening in the query. I have been trying to figure it out myself. I would really like to learn what's the difference between below two queries and how does the performance gain happen ? what's the logic behind it ?

I'm new to these advance techniques. I hope someone will help me out here. Given that I read the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) which does not give me a clue.

Method 1 :

```
SELECT
   *       
FROM
   tracker       
WHERE
   reservation_id IN (
      SELECT
         reservation_id                                 
      FROM
         tracker                                 
      GROUP  BY
         reservation_id                                 
      HAVING
         (
            method = 1                                          
            AND type = 0                                          
            AND Count(*) > 1 
         )                                         
         OR (
            method = 1                                              
            AND type = 1                                              
            AND Count(*) > 1 
         )                                         
         OR (
            method = 2                                              
            AND type = 2                                              
            AND Count(*) > 0 
         )                                         
         OR (
            method = 3                                              
            AND type = 0                                              
            AND Count(*) > 0 
         )                                         
         OR (
            method = 3                                              
            AND type = 1                                              
            AND Count(*) > 1 
         )                                         
         OR (
            method = 3                                              
            AND type = 3                                              
            AND Count(*) > 0 
         )
   )
```

Method 2 :

```
SELECT
   *                                
FROM
   `tracker` t                                
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT
         reservation_id                                              
      FROM
         `tracker` t3                                              
      WHERE
         t3.reservation_id = t.reservation_id                                              
      GROUP BY
         reservation_id                                              
      HAVING
         (
            METHOD = 1 
            AND TYPE = 0 
            AND COUNT(*) > 1
         ) 
         OR                                                     
         (
            METHOD = 1 
            AND TYPE = 1 
            AND COUNT(*) > 1
         ) 
         OR                                                    
         (
            METHOD = 2 
            AND TYPE = 2 
            AND COUNT(*) > 0
         ) 
         OR                                                     
         (
            METHOD = 3 
            AND TYPE = 0 
            AND COUNT(*) > 0
         ) 
         OR                                                     
         (
            METHOD = 3 
            AND TYPE = 1 
            AND COUNT(*) > 1
         ) 
         OR                                                     
         (
            METHOD = 3 
            AND TYPE = 3 
            AND COUNT(*) > 0
         )                                             
   )
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

An [**`Explain Plan`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) would have shown you why exactly you should use `Exists`. Usually the question comes `Exists vs Count(*)`.  `Exists` is faster. Why?

- With regard to challenges present by NULL: when **subquery returns `Null`, for IN the entire query becomes `Null`**. So you need to handle that as well. But using `Exist`, it's merely a `false`. Much easier to cope. Simply `IN` can't compare anything with `Null` but `Exists` can.
- e.g. `Exists (Select * from yourtable where bla = 'blabla');` you get true/false the moment **one hit is found/matched**.
- In this case `IN` sort of takes the position of the `Count(*)` to select **ALL** matching rows based on the `WHERE` because it's comparing all values.

**But don't forget this either:**

- `EXISTS` executes at high speed against `IN` : when the subquery results is very large.
- `IN` gets ahead of `EXISTS` : when the subquery results is very small.

**Reference to for more details:**

- [subquery using IN](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Subquery_typo_with_using_in).
- [IN - subquery optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/in-subquery-optimization.html)
- [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-subquery).

Comment: 20 rows is large or small ?

Comment: So far all my tests have come with IN as a better optimized query. Even the explain select shows a better usage of the indexes. I have yet to see a single case where Exists is better than In (Big table too. Like 1M rows for one and 100k on the child table). Maybe Exists is more optimized in a newer MySQL version?

Answer (score 4):

Method 2 is fast because it is using `EXISTS` operator, where I `MySQL` do not load any results.
As mentioned in your [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) link as well, that it omits whatever is there in `SELECT` clause. It only checks  for the first value that matches the criteria, once found it sets the condition `TRUE` and moves for further processing.

On the other side Method 1 has `IN` operator which loads all possible values and then matches it. Condition is set `TRUE` only when exact match is found which is time consuming process.

Hence your method 2 is fast.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

The **EXISTS** operator is a Boolean operator that returns either true or false. The EXISTS operator is often used the in a [subquery](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) to test for an “*exist*” condition.

```
SELECT 
    select_list
FROM
    a_table
WHERE
    [NOT] EXISTS(subquery);
```

If the subquery returns any row, the **EXISTS** operator returns true, otherwise, it returns false.

In addition, the **EXISTS** operator terminates further processing immediately once it finds a matching row. Because of this characteristic, you can use the **EXISTS** operator to improve the performance of the query in some cases.

The **NOT** operator negates the **EXISTS** operator. In other words, the **NOT EXISTS** returns true if the subquery returns no row, otherwise it returns false.

You can use **SELECT ***, **SELECT column**, **SELECT a_constant**, or anything in the subquery. The results are the same because MySQL ignores the **select_list** that appears in the *SELECT* clause.

The reason is that the **EXISTS** operator works based on the “at least found” principle. It returns true and stops scanning table once at least one matching row found.

On the other hands, when the **IN** operator is combined with a subquery, MySQL must process the subquery first and then uses the result of the subquery to process the whole query.

The general rule of thumb is that if the subquery contains a large volume of data, the **EXISTS** operator provides a better performance.

However, the query that uses the **IN** operator will perform faster if the result set returned from the subquery is very small.

For detail explanations and examples: [MySQL EXISTS - mysqltutorial.org](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-exists/)

Answer (score 0):

The second Method is faster because you've got this like there "WHERE t3.reservation_id = t.reservation_id". In the first case your subquery has to do a full scan into the table to verify the information. However at the 2o Method the subquery knows exactly what it is looking for and once it is found is checked the having condition then.

Answer (score -3):

Their Official Documentation.[SubQuery Optimization with Exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html)