# Trouble debugging a slow query

Tags: mysql, indexing, subquery

I am having trouble debugging a slow query, when I take it appart they perform relatively fast, let me break it down for you:

The first query, which is my subquery, groups all rows by `lmu_id` (currently only 2 unique ones) and returns the `max(id)` in other words the last inserted row.

```
SELECT max(id) FROM `position` GROUP by lmu_id  
-> 15055,15091
```

**2 total, Query took 0.0030 seconds**

The outer query retrieves the full row of those two positions, so here I've manually inserted the ids `(15055,15091)`

```
SELECT * FROM `position` WHERE id IN (15055,15091)
```

**2 total, Query took 0.1169 sec**

Not the fastest query, but still a bink of an eye.

Now my problem is I do not understand why if I combine these two queries the whole system crashes:

```
SELECT * FROM `position` AS p1 WHERE p1.id IN (SELECT max(id) FROM `position` AS p2 GROUP by p2.lmu_id)
```

**takes forever, 100% cpu, crashing, lost patience after 2 minutes, service mysql restart**

For your reference I did an explain of the query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `position` AS p1 WHERE p1.id IN (SELECT max(p2.id) FROM `position` AS p2 GROUP by p2.lmu_id)
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys   key                     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             p1      ALL     NULL            NULL                    NULL        NULL    7613    Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  p2      index   NULL            position_lmu_id_index   5           NULL    1268    Using index
```

`id` is the primary key, and `lmu_id` is a foreign key and also indexed.
I'm really stumped. Why is the final query taking so long/crashing? What other things shoud I look in to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins can work too.

```
SELECT *
FROM `position` AS p1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) FROM `position` GROUP by lmu_id) p2 on (p1.id = p2.id)
```

Scott's answer is good too, as I find `EXISTS` tends to run quite fast as well. In general, avoid `IN`.

Also try

```
SELECT *
FROM `position` AS p1
GROUP BY p1.lmu_id
HAVING p1.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM `position` where lmu_id = p1.lmu_id)
```

Comment: Brilliant, the INNER JOIN  query took 0.0003 sec, this is much better

Comment: The `having` query took 0.0200 sec

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using EXISTS runs much faster than IN sub selects.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

[Subqueries with EXISTS vs IN - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190788/subqueries-with-exists-vs-in-mysql)

Comment: how would he use `EXISTS` in his context? He is trying to 'join' the other table on a value that comes from the sub query. I don't think `EXISTS` will help here.

Comment: I was not able to figure out how to use `EXISTS` to behave as I expected, like nl-x mentioned