# How to determine the collection is available in a table without SELECT iteration in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

SELECT with WHERE Clause returns a new sequence of items matching the predicate by iteration.

Is there is any way to predict the given Search Criteria is available or not (Boolean) in MySQL?

Sample SQL

```
CREATE TABLE Ledger
(
PersonID int,
ldate date,    
dr float,
cr float,
bal float
);

INSERT INTO Ledger(PersonID, ldate, dr, cr, bal)
VALUES 
('1001', '2016-01-23', 105 ,0 ,0),
('1001', '2016-01-24', 0, 5.25, 0),
('1002', '2016-01-24', 0, 150, 0),
('1001', '2016-01-25', 0, 15, 0),
('1002', '2016-01-25', 73, 0, 0);
```

Here I need to Check PersonID 1002 is exist or not

Common Way of Checking is

```
SELECT COUNT(PersonID) > 0 AS my_bool FROM Ledger WHERE PersonID = 1002

SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 AS my_bool FROM Ledger WHERE ldate = '2016-01-24' AND (bal > 75 AND bal <100)
```

The above two queries are only for sample.

But, the above SELECT Query iterates the whole collection and filters the result. It degrades the Performance in a very Big Database Collection (over 300k active records).

Is there's a version with a predicate (in which case it returns whether or not any items match) and a version without (in which case it returns whether the query-so-far contains any items).

Here I given a very simple WHERE Clause. But in real scenario there is
 complex WHERE Clause. .NET there is a method .Any() it predicts the
 collection instead of .Where().

How to achieve this in a efficient way?

Comment: Create index on PersonID in order to minimize the number of rows scan.

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu - The above SQL is a sample but in main database the Column is a Indexed Column. Here I given a very simple WHERE Clause. But in real scenario there is complex WHERE Clause. Kindly assist me..

Comment: Then share your complex query please.

Comment: If you have too much data you can also consider partitioning of data where particular range of record store into partitions, so only limited data will scanned while searching.

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu I updated the query. Kindly check it once.

Comment: @Code-Monk Kindly elaborate your idea

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html

Comment: If there are indexes correspond to the WHERE clause it *doesn't* iterate over the entire table, or degrade the performance. That's the *point.*

Comment: @EJP I Can't make each Column to Index. Currently I'm having 3 Lakh active records.

Comment: Yeah...Index will boost the performance but if OP has too much data then can consider partitioning of data to improve performance.

Comment: @EJP In .NET there is a method .Any() it predicts the collection instead of .Where(). I'm asking as like that. Is there is any other way to check?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan That would correspond to `COUNT(*) > 0` which you're already doing. Still waiting for your WHERE clause ...

Answer (score 1):

You can optimise by using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM Ledger 
  WHERE ldate = '2016-01-24' 
  AND (bal > 75 AND bal < 100)
) AS my_bool
```

It will return as soon as a match is found.

[Click here to have a play on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12f59/6)

More info here:

[Optimizing Subqueries with EXISTS Strategy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html)

[Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

[Subqueries with EXISTS vs IN - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190788/subqueries-with-exists-vs-in-mysql)