# How can I make this UPDATE query faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make this update query more efficient.

```
UPDATE #table_name# SET #column_name2# = 1 WHERE #column_name1# in (A list of data)
```

Right now it takes more than 2 minute to finish the job when my list of data is quite large. Here is the result of explain of this query:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | #table_name# | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 38      | NULL | 763719 | Using where; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------+
```

In class, I was told that an OK query should at least have a type of `range` and is better to reach `ref`. Right now mine is `index`, which is the second slowest I think. I'm wondering if there's a way to optimize that.

Here is the table format:

```
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| #column_name1#     | varchar(12) | NO   | PRI |                   |       |
| #column_name2#     | tinyint(4)  | NO   |     | 0                 |       |
| #column_name3#     | tinyint(4)  | NO   |     | 0                 |       |
| ENTRY_TIME         | datetime    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

My friend suggested me that using `exists` rather than `in` clause may help. However, it looks like I cannot use `exists` like `exists (A list of data)`

Comment: `Exists` wants a select statement. It is a bit different to `in`. But can be faster than `in`. But there is a difference in handling `null` values. for more information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190788/subqueries-with-exists-vs-in-mysql

Comment: Are you updating 763719 records? that's going to be slow no matter what

Comment: You say "when my list of data is quite large." How large?

Comment: @e4c5 I'm not updating that many. ~500 records are updated

Comment: @OllieJones It's around 500 elements

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
UPDATE #table_name#
    SET #column_name2# = 1
    WHERE #column_name1# in (A list of data);
```

You want an index on `#table_name#(#column_name1#)`.

Do note that the number of records being updated has a very big impact on performance.  If the "list of data" is really a subquery, then other methods are likely to be more helpful for improving performance.

Comment: Do I need to make it an index on a primary key? I think it's an index already

Comment: @BingGan . . . If it is already *the* primary key, then an additional index is not necessary.  If it is the first key of a compound primary key, then an additional index is not necessary.  If it is a subsequent key of a primary key, then you do want the index.