# Performance of sub-query in IN clause with large tables in delete query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering, why queries with IN-Operator are much slower than a simple `SELECT`.

Let me demonstrate my oberservations on an example:

```
Query1: SELECT VIDEO_ID FROM videos (about 8000 rows with 1 column)

Query2: DELETE FROM video_snapshot WHERE video_snapshot.VIDEO_ID IN (Query1)
```

video_snapshot is a very big table with over 7.000.000 rows but VIDEO_ID is indexed, so querys with VIDEO_ID in a `WHERE`-clause are fast enough.

How does the `IN`-Operator work? I guessed that this is just a short form for serveral `WHERE` clauses.

I am using MariaDB 10.1.16 on XAMPP

Comment: Maybe this one can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14194444/1050927

Comment: what does explain say

Comment: It is slow because you are doing a correlated subquery.  Note you never gave a schema for analysis. That would be done with `show create table xyz` for any relevant table. You also did not give `Query1`. So that wasn't very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large data-set table `IN` clause performance is very slow in this case you can use `INNER JOIN` with delete query

```
DELETE video_snapshot FROM video_snapshot
INNER JOIN videos ON video_snapshot.VIDEO_ID=videos.VIDEO_ID;
```

> In my experience IN is a very slow operator, since SQL normally
>   evaluates it as a series of WHERE clauses separated by "OR" (WHERE x=Y
>   OR x=Z OR...).. BUT mainly explicit join is faster when need to compare field with other table field.

Comment: This query was very fast. Thank you.

Why is `IN` so slow with large data sets?