# How to select all rows from a table which are not in other table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables in mysql Database (mariaDB) name **products** and **order**.
In product table  there is column **productid** which is type of `int(11)` and set as primary key as well as auto increment. While order table has reference of **productid** column
the name is **not same** and no foreign key is used . The name of column in `order` table  is set to `pid` and type is `varchar`.

I want all the rows from `products` table  whose `productid` is not present in `order` table .

this databases is used by an android application as well as web application. so major changes like renaming columns is not feasible.

My current approach is using programing . Get list of all `productid` from `products` and then search for them in `order` table one by one . This is taking a lot of time as number of products in table are about 500k
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Note that `order` is a reserved word in MySQL, rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do a query to get the products:

```
SELECT products.productid, order.orderid 
FROM products
LEFT JOIN order ON order.pid = products.productid
WHERE order.orderid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into "exists" statements.

Your request would look like

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1 FROM orders 
      WHERE orders.productid = products.productid);
```

There are other possibilities, and I'm no expert on DB to discuss further of their merits, but you can read more about that on [Subqueries with EXISTS vs IN - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190788/subqueries-with-exists-vs-in-mysql) . In my own experience (which may or may not be the same as yours) I find using "EXISTS" easier to read and performant enough

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT products.productid 
LEFT JOIN `order` 
ON(products.productid=CAST(`order`.pid AS INTEGER))
WHERE `order`.pid is null;
```